# Merge assoiative array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have to merge an associative array in a specifc way. With PHP. There is no way to get the data allready merged.

That schould convert this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [name] => Color
           [value] => Array
               (
                   [0] => white
               )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Size
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 38cm
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Color
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => red
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Size
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 38cm
                )

        )

)
```

To an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array 
        (
           [name] => Color
           [value] => Array
              (
                  [0] => white
                  [1] => red
              )
        )

    [1] => Array 
        (
           [name] => Size
           [value] => Array
              (
                  [0] => 38cm
              )
        )
)
```

So it should delete all duplicate [name] values, but merging the [value] values, associated to a name, together.

It's actualy not a real 'merging' of 2 or more arrays, but merging the arrys's whithin a multidimensional array.

I tryed this with a simple foreach, and a check for existing values and keys, but I had no success at all. Now I hope that somebody could set my thining.

Thanks in advance!

(Sorry for my bad english, it's not my native language)

Comment: Yes, `array_unique($variationSpecificSet, SORT_REGULAR);` kills element [3], which is absolutely correct. But the array_merge() functions doens't work for me because I've only one array. What I need is to merge the arrys within this one array. Or do I missunderstand array_merge()?

Answer (score 0):

Let the array be $arr;

```
$arr2[0]['name'] = 'Color';
$arr2[1]['name'] = 'Size';
$c1=0;
foreach($arr as $ar)
{
    if(c1 % 2 == 0)
    {
      $arr2[0]['value'][] = $ar['value'];
    }
    else
    {
     $arr2[1]['value'][] = $ar['value'];
    }
$c1++;
}
```

Use $arr2;

So for each item its putting it to one of the new array value.

You may have to use **$ar['value'][0]** if **$ar['value']** doesn't work.

Just check it.

Hope it helps!

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That particular code doesn't work for me, because it mixed up color and size in some test cases. But it brougth me to the final solution, with two foreach loops. That handles also other cases. Sorry, but because of downvoting my question I decided not to publish my solution.